# Two random variables that map the same event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose you have a 10-sided fair die numbered 0 to 9. Define random variable $X$ to be 1 if the die lands on a number less than 5 (or 0 otherwise) and define random variable $Y$ to be 1 if the die lands on a number less than 8 (or 0 otherwise).

For example, if a 3 is rolled, then $X=Y=1$. If 6 is rolled then $X=0$ and $Y=1$, etc.

Is there a special term for $X$ and $Y$? Clearly they are correlated since $X=1\rightarrow Y=1$ and $Y=0 \rightarrow X=0$, but they are also simultaneously mapping the same random event to $\{0,1\}$, just in slightly different ways.

Comment: You are just dealing with two Bernoulli-distributed random variables $X,Y$ defined on the same probability space that are related in the sense that $X\leq Y$ and $X\neq Y$. That is not an usual situation and I don't think that there is special terminology for that. Events are not mapped by random variables but outcomes are. E.g. $X$ sends $4$ to $1$.

Comment: Ah, I expected my terminology was off, but that makes sense. If you're curious, this unusual situation was inspired by random number sharing in Monte Carlo simulation, for example, the variance reduction technique "antithetic variates" does something similar to what I described above. So maybe its more of a statistics concept. Thanks again.